# Are True and False equal to Yes and No when specifying argument/attribute values in terms of funcationality and performance?

Tags: coldfusion

Are there any known functional or performance differences in using yes|no vs. true|false? 
ColdFusion documentation states that values for boolean-type attributes are specified with yes/no. For example, <cfargument required="yes|no" ....> I have used true and false in place of yes|no and have seen no unexpected functionality.

[EDIT]
I appreciate the responses, perhaps I am thinking a bit more general in this case.

ColdFusion documentation states that the expected value is 'yes|no' for some parameters, such as for [cfargument required](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e47.html). Is there any insight into why yes|no is documented as the only expected values, rather than also true|false or stating 'any boolean value' is expected? Seems a bit ambiguous to not indicate any boolean type rather than only state 'yes|no' if either A)We are to assume 'any boolean' B)There is an actual performance difference. Thoughts?

Comment: Basically the ColdFusion documentation is a mine field of contradictions and inaccuracies. So sadly the reason is because the person who wrote that page decided he like yes / no whereas a person who wrote a different page liked true / false. It makes it tough for new users. My suggestion is decide which pairing you like and be consistent. They all work the same way.

Comment: I suspect a good portion of it is simply due to mixing old/new documentation. They often recycle the docs for existing tags/functions from one version to another (with minor modifications or additions for new attributes). So while newer documentation tends to use true/false, the yes/no legacy in the older documentation continues to linger on ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"yes/no"` is a few characters less to type.

`"true/false"` (and true/false) is more in line with other programming languages.

In terms of performance, they are all strings as far as CF is concerned. It is not until you try to use them in conditional logic that they magically change into other data types, like java.lang.Boolean. The conversion between strings and Booleans and back again is very fast. It's what CF does most of the time. You'd be hard pressed finding any reliable tests proving one faster than the other.

For code maintainability/readability it's best to stick with one or the other.

Some legacy CF tag functions specifically require "yes/no". They simply will not work with "true/false". I believe this is no longer the case in CF9+.

Don't rely on the ColdFusion documentation being accurate or up to date. Almost all of the methods that list "yes/no" as the default/allowed values actually support any kind of boolean value. "yes/no", "true/false", true/false, 1/0, etc.

IMHO using "yes/no" for booleans is crazy. Backwards compatibility from the old CF5 era. Sucks that Adobe are still using it to output java Booleans.

eg. `writeDump( var: (not true) );` gives you "NO". But, I wanted `false`?! Grrr.

You can tell what java class your variable is currently by calling `myVar.getClass().getName()`. You can use it to watch CF casting your data from Boolean to String and back to Boolean again, like magic.

Comment: This answer is in line with what I needed to know - setting boolean arguments, rather than testing boolean values. I also agree that using true/false is more appropriate. On a team however, it is more difficult to implement a standard when the use of yes/no is used simply because the documentation indicates these are the values.

Comment: Re: *I believe this is no longer the case in CF9+.* I wish. `<cfhttp getAsBinary=".."> still requires "yes/no" in CF10. I always forget that one.

Answer (score 9):

ColdFusion evaluates yes/no, true/false, 1 (or any non-zero number)/0 equally. This makes it easy to make shortcut booleans like `<cfif myquery.recordcount>` or `<cfif len(FORM.myVar)>` without having to convert the integer into a true/false.

Comment: Not just positive integers, but any non-zero number will be considered "true".

Comment: I have a post on this that discusses the ins and outs in mind-numbing detail :)  http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/2/5/Booleans.and.Coldfusion

Comment: I do prefer using the boolean evaluation for conditional statements. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, you could try this. For me, ten million iterations of not using "yes" resulted in 100 fewer milliseconds for the most part.

```
<cfscript>
bln = true;
starttime = getTickCount();

for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){
if(bln eq true)
  foo="bar";
}
writeOutput(getTickCount()-startTime & '<br />');

starttime = getTickCount();

for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){
if(bln eq "yes")
  foo="bar";
}
writeOutput(getTickCount()-startTime & '<br />');
</cfscript>
```

Comment: `getTickCount()` isnt very precise. Try `sys = createObject('java','java.lang.System');` then use `start = sys.nanoTime();` to get a "tick" in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded a project to CF2016 and suddenly began getting java.lang.VerifyError "Incompatible argument to function" errors.  Turned out to be in cfform, we were using accessible="true". Changing the value to "yes" does ***not*** remove the error.  Removing the entire "accessible" form tag does.  Rather than figuring out what Flash-related nightmare this represents, we removed it from our forms.

Thanks, Adobe.